# 'Ray' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Tags: unity-game-engine

Even in the documentation, this line is indicated  **"Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward); "**, but I get an error.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ray : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.yellow);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you just named your own class `Ray`  as well which is a `MonoBehaviour` and doesn't have a constructor with parameters.

Now you'll have to use the explicit namespace like

```c#
void Update()
{
    var ray = new UnityEngine.Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.yellow);
}
```

In general though you should use a better class name which is more descriptive like in your case e.g. `RayVisualizer` or something similar.